# Loading >= 10 GB data table into R through Snowflake API

Tags: r

So I've been searching online for some help on this, and couldn't find exactly what I was looking for.

I was trying to load in a large dataset from Snowflake (21 GB) into R, but my computer's RAM size is 16 GB - so I ended up creating 3 different datasets from the large one to try to reduce the size (~10 GB, ~11 GB, ~127 MB). This is still taking quite a bit of time (it's been running for over an hour for the 10 GB portion).

I've set my java parameters as: `options(java.parameters = c("-Xms32768M","-Xmx65536M"))`. And in terms of how I got in the data, I load my Snowflake data in through by using Snowflake's JDBC driver, where the jdbcConnection holds my login parameters and extract my data by a simple select statement:

```
df <- 
dbGetQuery(jdbcConnection,
           "select * from table")
```

My backup option right now is just to make the dataframes even smaller, and try to load it in that way. But I'm thinking this isn't the best option. Is there a better way to approach loading all this data in through Snowflake?

Comment: I don't envy your situation. I'll be a little surprised if you get your 10GB to load cleanly into R. If you do, though, you might really want (*need*?!?) to use `data.table` for in-place work on the data. Since R tends to copy-on-write in many situations, you'll find that seemingly simple operations will crush your R. I think your plan to make then even smaller is likely going to be necessary. (How are you measuring "21 GB"? As an example of why this is important: `mtcars` saved as a CSV is 1336 bytes, but in R, `object.size(mtcars)` yields `7208 bytes`.)

Comment: Damn. This is depressing. It's still been running, now over a few hours so I just stopped the run after seeing your comment. And I just grabbed the table sizes from Snowflake. Do you think Python's memory storage capabilities might be more advanced than R, and I should shift on over there?

Comment: R's `data.table` is analogous (in your lens of "efficient") to python's memory model, in that most changes to values in the frame are done in-place, not copy-on-write. It does (like python) copy at times, but that is unavoidable in some situations. If you haven't used `data.table` before, its syntax can be daunting; if you're comfortable instead with `dplyr`, there is [`dtplyr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dtplyr/index.html) which is *close* (but I haven't evaluated performance or these memory claims).

Comment: Ah, helpful - thank you @r2evans, I'll give dtplyr a go if I can get the data in. Going to try to break it down into smaller chunks right now.

Comment: This problem sounds like it *begs* a divide-and-conquer mindset: break it up to a much smaller bite of data and work on a smaller scale. I don't know the processing you're doing, but while R can deal with data this large (given enough memory), it might be much more efficient to work on 1/10th of the data (or smaller) instead of 1/3rd. Good luck!